# Maximising spin on a table tennis ball: speed or acceleration?

Tags: everyday-life, projectile, rotation, contact-mechanics

In table tennis it is often desirable to produce as much spin on the ball as possible using a glancing contact. (The rubber covering of a table tennis bat is typically highly elastic and has a high coefficient of friction.) Anecdotally, the view is sometimes expressed that acceleration at the point of contact is more important than speed. I take this to mean that when the ball is hit with the bat at the same angle and travelling in the same direction, it is possible for a bat at a lower velocity but with some acceleration to impart more spin on the ball than a bat travelling at a constant higher velocity (higher than the maximum speed of the accelerating bat) without acceleration.

Is this true? If so, why, and how can the optimal contact (in terms of speed and acceleration) to produce maximum spin be determined?

Comment: The "dwell time" when the paddle is in contact with the ball is on the order of 1ms. On that time scale, the bat has a nearly constant velocity whether it's accelerating or not (at 10G's of acceleration, it results in 0.1m/s velocity change, perhaps 1% change in speed). I think the idea is that the slower bat can perhaps impart greater acceleration to the ball by being in contact with it longer, not that the bat itself needs to be accelerating.